# Error '.xls' is in a different format than specified by the file extension

Tags: excel, extjs

I found a plugin that helps me export ExtJS grid data into MS Excel sheet.
http://druckit.wordpress.com/2013/10/26/generate-an-excel-file-from-an-ext-js-4-grid/

all works great except for the error I'm getting before opening the file.

[image]

Peace of my code:

```
if (Ext.isChrome || Ext.isGecko) { // local download
            var gridEl = this.getEl();

            var el = Ext.DomHelper.append(gridEl, {
                tag: "a",
               download: title + "-" + Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d') + '.xls',
               href: location
            });

            el.click();

            Ext.fly(el).destroy();

        }
```

One solution suggested that i remove the apostrophe so i tried:

```
download: title + "-" + Ext.Date.format(new Date(), "Y-m-d") + ".xls",
```

But no luck. Any idea?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the download link but with the content of the downloaded data. The link tells Excel that it should be a *.xls file (Excel up to 2003)  but it contains not Excel data but HTML or XML.

Comment: @shadin: You can change the file extension to xlsx or force the Excel object to save in the XLS format using XlFileFormat.xlExcel8.

Comment: @Paresh J:I don't believe that changing the extension will make something better. I suspect then Excel will open the data not more because the data is SpreadsheetML for Excel up to 2003 and not OpenXML. And "force the Excel object to save in the XLS format using XlFileFormat.xlExcel8" is a good point. But how to do that with http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/ ?

Comment: @Shadin: Thank you for adding the link to the plug in you have used. As I suspected the plug in generates SpreadsheetML http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats . The native type of this is XML not XLS. But as *.xml file Excel will only open this by default, if it is registered as the default application for XML. So either you live with the warning message or you use something what really can create Excel files.

Comment: I see. I get it know. Many thanks Axel!